# Confused about ASP.NET Core Identity and IdentityServer 4 in case of implementing an API for external access

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have a single ASP.NET Core 3.1.8 web application which uses ASP.NET Identity.
Now I've added some ***externally*** callable REST API.

I am stuck on how to add token(?) based authentication to my API.
It seems that ASP.NET Identity does not support API authentication. In my old .NET Framework Web App I used

```
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

so I had a token endpoint, where external client could ask for a valid token.

Now I read about to have API authentication I should use either AD or AD B2C or IdentityServer 4. I am OK with IdentityServer 4 option, but something is not clear

- IdentityServer will completely replace my ASP.NET Identity? I still want to use the login UI and my existing interactive login logic and UI.
- I've read about plug in ASP Identity to IdentityServer 4. So do I have to integrate my existing ASP Identity with IdentityServer 4?
- Is it OK to host IdentityServer 4 within the very same Web App, where the UI, and the API is hosted?
- I've tried to read the ASP.NET Core repo's source both the 3.1.8 and 5.0.0-rc.1, to get some direction. I would not like to go in some direction what will be considered as suboptimal in the next .NET 5 release. I know that there is a complete another way to solve this: AD or AD B2C, and I also have a solution template for that. As an alternative I would like to have a "self contained" solution too, so that's why I invested to ASP Identity. What would be the righ future direction in this track (self-contained) to implement external API authentication?

Answer (score 1):

To protect the API itself you typically use the [following](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html):

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
    });
```

I recommend that if you use IdentityServer, you should put it on its own service, because otherwise its really hard to figure out what's going on and who is doing what.

IdentityServer does not deal with users, so you need to implement the user database (signup/forgotten password...) by yourself. You can use ASP.NET Identity for that.

**IdentityServer will completely replace my ASP.NET Identity?**

I would say that it depends on your needs, in some cases IdentityServer replaces ASP.NET Identity, and in some cases not. If you just have a single service to protect, then IdentityServer is probably overkill, because there's a lot to learn.